# I want to Show only Next div by clicking next and also by clicking preview as same process. But cant find any solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click all off next and previous divs are shown. But I want to show only the next div by clicking "next" for each time and rest of them should hidden. And also for previous div as the same process. But I can't get any solution. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.first:hidden:first').show();
  });
  $(".pre").click(function() {
    $(this).prevAll('.first:hidden:first').show();
  });
});

<div class="wrapper">
            <div class="pre">preview</div>
             <div class="next">Next</div>
            <div class="first">First</div>
            <div class="first">Second</div>
            <div class="first">Third</div>
            <div class="first">Forth</div>
            <div class="first">Fifth</div>

        </div>
```

Comment: As a nudge in the right direction, `$(this).prevAll('.first');` finds all elements of class `first` that appear before `$(this)`. So, you're looking for elements of `.first` that appear before `.pre` - of which, there are none. Additionally, you are only using `.show();`. If only one `.first` element should be visible at any time, you'll need to make use of `hide()`.

Comment: If you give me a sample code it will be helpful for me.

Comment: Aka, please do my work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
        $(this).parents(".wrapper").find(".first").slideToggle();

  });
});
</script>
```

It will hide all first div's by clicking on next div

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, at least for the next button.
Just reverse the logic for previous.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="prev">Prev</div>
  <div class="next">Next</div>
  <div class="block active">First</div>
  <div class="block">Second</div>
  <div class="block">Third</div>
  <div class="block">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.block{
  display: none;
}

.active{
  display: block;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(function(){
  $('.next').on('click', function(e){
    var $active = $('.active');
    $('.active').removeClass('active');

    if($active.is(':last-child')){
      //  I don't have a next, so show first instead
      $('.block').first().addClass('active');
    } else {
      $active.next().addClass('active')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: That's works fine for next but no activities for prev. Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'd suggest restructuring your HTML to be a bit more friendly and organized.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="first visible">First</div>
        <div class="first">Second</div>
        <div class="first">Third</div>
        <div class="first">Forth</div>
        <div class="first">Fifth</div>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <a class="pre">PREVIOUS</a>
        <a class="next">NEXT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Next, you'll need to alter your JavaScript so that you're targeting the correct elements. If you want only one element to display at a time, you'll have to make use of `.hide()` as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".next").click(function() {
        //Show previous button
        $('.pre').show();

        //Find the element that's currently showing
        $showing = $('.content .first.visible').first();

        //Find the next element
        $next = $showing.next();

        //Change which div is showing
        $showing.removeClass("visible").hide();
        $next.addClass("visible").show();

        //If there's no more elements, hide the NEXT button
        if (!$next.next().length) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    $(".pre").click(function() {
        $('.next').show();

        $showing = $('.content .first.visible').first();
        $next = $showing.prev();
        $showing.removeClass("visible").hide();
        $next.addClass("visible").show();

        if (!$next.prev().length) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

Applying a class to the visible element is a good way to keep track of which elements are shown and hidden. To hide the rest using CSS, you'll need:

```
.first:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
}
```

The only thing I haven't added here is the logic to handle clicking "Previous" during the first element, or "Next" during the last.

Here is how it looks: https://jsfiddle.net/ajgugtu9/8/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need actually this thing. All are well. If please help me to restrict when I reached the last div it will not give any activities for next and  preview. Thank you so much.

Comment: I've edited my answer and updated the JSFiddle link.

Comment: no problem. if you feel that your question has been adequately answered and your issue resolved, please consider [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick and easy way to do this:

```js
$('.next').click(function() {
  if ($('.first:visible').next().length) {
    $('.first:visible').next().show()
    $('.first:visible').first().hide()
  }
})
$('.pre').click(function() {
  if ($('.first:visible').prev('.first').length) {

    $('.first:visible').prev().show()
    $('.first:visible').last().hide()
  }
})
$('.first').first().show()
```

```css
.first {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="pre">Previous</div>
  <div class="next">Next</div>
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="first">Second</div>
  <div class="first">Third</div>
  <div class="first">Forth</div>
  <div class="first">Fifth</div>
</div>
```

The jQuery works by binding the click event to your previous and next divs. When clicking either one the code checks to see if the previous or next element with the class `first` exists. If it does then it will show that item and hide the existing one.